# Azure Search: return top documents for each facet

Tags: azure, search, facet

Starting situation:

I created an index with multiple fields, one of those fields is facetable.
After indexing i executed search queries by setting a facet on this specific field. The returned results match the desired behaviour, everything works fine.

It is not necessary that all results which match the search term are returned. Therefore i set the "$top" parameter to 50, and only the first 50 results are returned. But if the first facet includes more than 50 results, all other facets are not returned as a result.

My question is:
Is there a way to set the "$top" parameter for each facet? Or any other way to restrict the number of results for each facet?
For instance return only the top 5 documents of each facet.

Is there any solution for this issue? Or is there an approach to achieve the desired behaviour?

Hopefully someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely, 
You can do: 
Facet: "foo",sort: value(or count),count:5(or whatever value you want)

For your facet query "count" is the number of items you want to get and by combining it with sort you can get your solution

[You will find more detailed information here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
But it didn´t solve my problem. " Facet: "foo", count: 5" just returns the five "highest ranked" facets sorted by whatever.
But i want to get all facets as a result, each of these facets should include the top five results for this specific facet.
I don´t want to limit the number of the returned facets, I want to limit the number of result documents for each facet.
Hopefully it´s more understandable now

Comment: Than the only way is to do that (for now at least) is to have multiple queries.
You can initially send a query that requests 0 results but only facets and from the data you receive, send subsequent queries.

Here is my attempt to provide a better example... 
If this was an SQL query, your facets would be the GROUP BY on your WHERE,  in a separate segment from your results. The only thing you can do from there is send more requests based on said segment

Comment: I had the same idea, sadly it is not an option due to performance issues.

Comment: You should give it a shot regardless. We had a similar situation with a recent project and we ended up doing a separate query for each facet just to simulate [link](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters)Solr's excluding Filters[/link] feature. After playing around quite a bit with search parameters performance Azure Search really "delivered" and performance was not an issue. If you include some minor parallelism and have the appropriate pricing tier on your Azure Search plan i strongly believe performance will not be an issue.